# Searching, recursively, the children of all divs of a certain class

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="testClass">
    <div>
        <select name="specialName123">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="testClass">
    <div>
        <span id="someSpan">
            <select name="specialName123">
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How do I select the two above divs on my page based on the fact that they have the class "testClass" and have a select that has "123" in it's name?

I understand I can find all selects like so `$('select[name*="123"]')`, and I can use `$(".testClass")` to select the appropriate divs. But how do I put these together in the way I need to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `closest` method:

```
$('select[name*="123"]').closest('.testClass')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj7kL/)

or:

```
$('.testClass').has("select[name*=123]")
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj7kL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not:

```
$('.testClass select[name*="123"]')
```

It maches any children of testclass (any depth) that is a select-box with name containing 123.

Comment: I don't think this selects the actual div though does it?

Comment: as noted it will select the select element and not the div

Comment: Aaah, my bad. Misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `find` method to get all the descendants of `testClass`, which you can then filter by a selector:

`$('.testClass').find('select[name*="123"]');`

Comment: Similarly to to OptimusCrime's suggestion - does this not just select the selects? I want the whole div selected.

Comment: I see, I was misunderstanding your question. You are correct - this will just select the selects.

Comment: Cool, well thanks a lot anyway, I've learnt something by your post that I'll bear in mind for the future.